# Use of activeX object on non-MFC applications

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008

I'd like to use an activeX component in Visual C++. The ocx file has been registered and I can insert the component in a dialog of the resource editor. But how I get a wrapper class to use the activeX object now?? On MFC applications, the editor creates a wrapper class for the ocx, but I'm not using MFC...

Thanks!
Henry

Answer (score -1):

The hosting of ActiveX controls is a right royal pain.
Basically, outside of some very thick tomes, there is no easy documentation on how to write a correct ActiveX host from scratch.

Start by taking a peek at webhost here: http://www.mvps.org/user32/ This was my experiment in creating the least amount of framework that could still host a shell.explorer ActiveX control.

The "core" API function to get you started down this road of madness is OleCreate - this will create a control given its CLSID, and a pointer to an IOleClientSite implementation thats going to be the, well, site for the control and some kind of IStorage implementation.

Comment: You could at least link to the relevant part of your website instead of using this as a shameless pitch to promote your other outdated content.

Comment: I wish it was a shameless pitch. As it was I had to google for my own - outdated - site. I have all but abandoned it. It does host a cab file with sample code in it that will do what the question asked. If I could have thought of any way to explain, on stackoverflow, how to implement an activex container from scratch in c++, I would have. Really.